# How do I execute/invoke a method from within onCreate?

Tags: java, android, methods, oncreate

I have a method that I want to invoke from within onCreate and then when that method finishes invoke a second method. 
This might not be the optimal way to do it so if there's an easier way let me know!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view_my_tickets); 
//I want to execute firstMethod from in here
}


public void firstMethod(){

     //code I want to execute on create
  //Only when this is finished- I want to execute secondMethod


 }

public void secondMethod(){

//only executed when firstMethod is finished

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason they are publi? Also, what is the problem?

Comment: When you say your firstMethod and secondMethod can you describe what these methods gonna return or do exactly?Arey you sure both are returning void?

Answer (score 2):

It is a straight forward process:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view_my_tickets); 
//I want to execute firstMethod from in here
firstMethod();
secondMethod();
}
```

For this to work flawlessly make sure that your firstMethod() doesn't have any threading involved.

**UPDATE** from the comments from @codeMagic:

> call secondMethod() from firstMethod()

Comment: Wouldn't you call `secondMethod()` from `firstMethod()`?

Comment: OP said only after execution of first method 2nd one should be executed.

Comment: @codeMagic I am sure its the same thing. If there are no threads then first firstMethod() will be executed then secondMethod() will be executed. Your solution is also a valid one so why dont you post it as an answer instead?\

Answer (score 0):

If firstMethod is a process intensive task, such reading a file or http requests, I suggest reading up on RxJava Observable (AsyncTask is no longer suggested, for long running operations)

It is useful when you with to perform a task, based on the result of another task.

Here is a [link](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/08/25/functional-reactive-programming-on-android-with-rxjava/) to a RxJava tutorial by Matthias Käppler.

Comment: "AsyncTask is no longer suggested" Do you have any references backing this claim?

Comment: Common issue, when an AsyncTask onPostExecute attempts to update the UI, but the UI(context) no longer exists (the user navigated away). In the link I provided, there is a section that outlines the issues with AsyncTasks